# Is it possible to make something like an event handler for when a bool toggles?

Tags: c#, variables, event-handling, toggle

say I have a variable `doSomethingWhenTrue`. Right now let's say it's `false`. Now every time it toggles values I want it to execute a function similar to this:

```
private void someResponseToToggledBool()
{
    If(boolInQuestion)
    {
        //do some stuff
        boolInQuestion = false;
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to do that? My (crappy) idea is to make a timer and assign this function to its tick value and throw it on another thread... But there has to be a more direct way than that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a property

```
private bool _boolInQuestion;
public bool BoolInQuestion
{
    get { return _boolInQuestion; }
    set
    {
         _boolInQuestion = value;
         //call method to do something
    }
}
```

In the setter you can also raise an event that's handled by whoever needs to react to the toggle, or even implent `INotifyPropertyChanged` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT**

As per your comment, you want this property to be static. You can achieve that by declaring both the field and property as `static`:

```
    private static bool _boolInQuestion;
    public static bool BoolInQuestion
    {
        get { return _boolInQuestion; }
        set
        {
            _boolInQuestion = value;
            //call method to do something
        }
    }
```

but this will require the method being invoked in the setter to be `static` as well. Alternatively, you can keep the property non-static and implement a [Singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx):

```
public sealed class BoolHolder
{
    private BoolHolder() { }

    private static BoolHolder instance = null;        
    public static BoolHolder Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new BoolHolder();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private bool _boolInQuestion;
    public bool BoolInQuestion
    {
        get { return _boolInQuestion; }
        set
        {
            _boolInQuestion = value;
            //call method to do something
        }
    }
}
```

and access it as `BoolHolder.Instance.BoolInQuestion`

Comment: gotta wait 7 minutes to mark as answer but this is perfect tyvm.

Comment: If I want to set the value of `BoolInQuestion` from another class how do I do that?

Comment: You can make both the `private` field and `public` property `static`, also the method called inside the setter needs to be static

Comment: can you edit your answer to show an example? when I say `public static bool BoolInQuestion` I get errors

Comment: @J.Doe edited answer .. depending on your use case you might want the simple `static` solution or the Singleton implementation

Comment: I can't make it static because I'm editing the properties of a winfrom control in my method. So the method can't be static. Let me try to wrap my head around this "Singleton". Have never seen one of these before. It might be my answer though

Comment: Consider also the option of raising an event from the setter and handling it in your winform control. This might enable you to use a static property (and static event) but also can have the benefit of keeping your components decoupled

Comment: sounds much more like what I need. Could you add one more example of raising an event? You've been extremely helpful thank you

Comment: Also I tried adding the Singleton you've shown above however I'm not sure what the syntax is to call a function from the same class? I placed the singleton in form1 and my function I want to call is also in form1. Tried `Form1.nameOfFunction()` but no dice.

Comment: You can use the same syntax `Form1.Instance.nameOfFunction()`. For the event case, basically u need to define an event in ur class, e.g. `public static event Action<bool> BoolChanged;` and in the setter do `if(BoolChanged !=null) BoolChanged(value);` to raise it. u can then handle it like any event `Form1.BoolChaned += ...`. Let me know if u have trouble implementing it and I can detail it once I get a chance

Answer (score 1):

use a property

```
private bool _doSomethingWhenTrue;
public bool doSomethingWhenTrue
{
    get
    {
        return _doSomethingWhenTrue;
    }
    set
    {
        _doSomethingWhenTrue = value;
        someResponseToToggledBool();
    }
 }
```

Comment: markus if I want to set the value of the bool from another class how do I do that? I can't set it now because I can make this bool static anymore

Comment: Up voted, just a note: u probably want to call the method *after* setting the field value

Comment: normally just set the variable https://www.dotnetperls.com/property what is the problem with static?

Comment: The method I have that executes when setting modifies a form control (working in winforms here). And those controls can't be manipulated from static methods so consequently my function isn't static, and thus can't be used in the set section... : (

Comment: there is no need to declare it static when using properties

Comment: I can't access the bool if it's non static from another class though, correct?

Comment: I need to be able to set that bool's value from another class. Is there's a way to do that without having it static?

Comment: If the class isn't static you can access it without having it static. See the examples in the links. The Tutorial on MSDN should make it clear. Properties are widly used in the .Net Framework and most of them are not static and are possible to access.